# Construction of a special function.

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions, symmetric-polynomials

Let $A$ is a some non-empty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$

There is a function:
$$P:A\times A \rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$$
$$P(x,y)=(x-a)\cdot(y-b)$$
And some constant number $c$ such $c\in A$.

Here is the problem:

> Construct new function $G$, that satisfy following equivalence relation: $G(x,y)=0\leftrightarrow(P(x,y)=0 \wedge x+y=c)$.

My attempt:

I tired to find that function like this:

$$G(x,y)=P(x,c-x)+P(c-y,y)$$

or like this:

$$G(x,y)=P(x,c-x)-2\cdot P(x,y)+P(c-y,y)$$.

But they are rather wrong.

Mayby some ideas?

EDIT: There is one thing extra. $0\le x,y \le c$

Comment: What do yo mean $P(x,y)=(x-a)(x-b)$ ? There is no $y$ in it.

Comment: Now i have made some edition

Comment: The tags seem mysterious to me. How are (symmetric) polynomials and generating functions relevant to the problem? Also, we can literally define $G$ to be such that this is true (i.e. the construction is rather trivial), so my guess is that there is some additional restriction on $G$ that you haven't told us. (For instance, must it be a polymomial?)

Comment: @mkultra. Explain why you say that $$G(x,y)=P(x,c-x)-P(c-y,y)$$

$$G(x,y)=P(x,c-x)-2\cdot P(x,y)+P(c-y,y)$$ are wrong.

Comment: I am very sorry. I thought that tag:"generating function" includes any function that we generate not only power series in that sense. I put tag "symmetric function" because there is a similiar situation: we just put a specific condition on variables. And yes i focus on polynomials not on logical functions.